# Estructurar un calendario HTML creado con ciclo For que repite fechas obtenidas desde MySQL

Tags: php, html, if, bucle-for, foreach

El siguiente código corresponde a un **ciclo For** que llena un *calendario hecho con HTML* (véase la siguiente imagen).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En este caso se muestran los eventos obtenidos por fechas desde la DB. Esas fechas se muestran dobles y trate de arreglarlo con un if pero solo me deja de repetir la fecha del ultimo evento.

```
Conexion :: abrirConexion();

// Set your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Get prev & next month
if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
$ym = $_GET['ym'];
} else {
// This month
$ym = date('Y-m');
}

// Check format
$timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
if ($timestamp === false) {
$ym = date('Y-m');
$timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
}

// Today
$hoy = date('Y-m-j', time());

// For H3 title
$mes = date('F / Y', $timestamp);//F era m POR SI ALGO

// Create prev & next month link     mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)
$anterior = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
$posterior = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));

// Number of days in the month
$contador_dias = date('t', $timestamp);

// 0:Sun 1:Mon 2:Tue ...
$texto = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
//$str = date('w', $timestamp);

// Create Calendar!!
$semanas = array();
$semana = '';

// Add empty cell
$semana .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $texto);
// AQUI SE OBTIENEN LOS EVENTOS DESDE LA DB
$eventos = DAOEvento :: consultarTodos(Conexion :: obtenerConexion());

for ($dia = 1; $dia <= $contador_dias; $dia++, $texto++) {
$fecha = $ym . '-' . $dia;
if ($hoy == $fecha) {
    $semana .= '<td class="hoy">' . '<a href="'.$ruta_elegida."?fecha=".$fecha.'&f=true">'.$dia.'</a>';
} else {
    foreach ($eventos as $evento) {//AQUI SE VERIFICAN LAS FECHAS DEL CALENDARIO CON LAS ENCONTRADAS EN LA BD
        $fecha_obtenida = $evento -> obtenerCierre();
        list($fecha_cierre, $hora_cierre) = explode(' ', $fecha_obtenida);
        $fecha_recuperada = $evento -> obtenerInicio(); 
        list($fecha_inicio, $hora_inicio) = explode(' ', $fecha_recuperada);
        if ($fecha_inicio == $fecha) {
        $semana .= '<td class="evento">' . '<a href="'.$ruta_elegida."?fecha=".$fecha.'&f=true&e=true">'.$dia.'</a>';
        }
    }
    if ($fecha !== $fecha_inicio) {//SIN ESTE IF LA FECHA 16 SE REPITE DOS VECES AL IGUAL QUE SE REPITE EL DIA 12 (EN ESTE CASO)
            $semana .= '<td>' . '<a href="'.$ruta_elegida."?fecha=".$fecha.'&f=true">'.$dia.'</a>';
    }
}
$semana .= '</td>';

 // End of the week OR End of the month
if ($texto % 7 == 6 || $dia == $contador_dias) {
    if ($dia == $contador_dias) {
        // Add empty cell
        $semana .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($texto % 7));
    }
    $semanas[] = '<tr>' . $semana . '</tr>';

    // Prepare for new week
    $semana = '';
}
}
?>
<div class="container">
<h3><a href="?ym=<?php echo $anterior; ?>">&lt;</a> <?php echo $mes; ?> <a href="?ym=<?php echo $posterior; ?>">&gt;</a></h3>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Dom</th>
        <th>Lun</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Mie</th>
        <th>Jue</th>
        <th>Vie</th>
        <th>Sab</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($semanas as $semana) {
        echo $semana;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Cabe mencionar que trate de cambiar el if de la "solucion" por un while o switch, pero me decía que las bytes se sobre pasaban o algo asi.

Agradezco de antemano las contribuciones para dar solución al problema.

Comment: Es difícil de seguir sin saber que contiene y que tiene que salir, pero yo diría que el if que has añadido sólo te funciona en el último caso porque está fuera del foreach y sólo se aplica al valor que toma la variable al acabar el bucle, para que funcione con los restantes deberías hacer esta comprobación dentro del bucle para cada evento.

Comment: Carmen ya he agregado mas del código que se utiliza en el archivo, para aclarar el panorama. No tengo claro tu comentario, porque si yo pongo el ultimo if de comprobación adentro entonces se daña toda la estructura de calendario. Donde dices que lo agregue o como y gracias!!

Comment: Dentro del foreach preguntas si la fecha es igual a la fecha de inicio, eso se ejecuta para todos los eventos, pero fuera añades un if para el caso de que sean diferentes (supongo que este es el que dices quita el duplicado del último evento), este segundo if debería estar dentro del foreach (a modo de else del if que ya está dentro, si es la condición complementaria) para que compruebe todos los eventos. Estoy asumiendo que la condición del segundo if sea distinto (!=), porque si tienes !== es otro tipo de comparación, y que los datos no vienen duplicados de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, intente lo que me dices, pero todo se repite dos veces y se ve peor, solo no se repite el dia de hoy (el primer if del for)